# Customize Welcome Message when linux user's login by ssh

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, uid

I want to print message when user login to linux using ssh like this message (welcome Mr john_097968) where john is username and 097968 is  UID Number . so how can I do that  using links terminal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually /etc/motd files contents are displayed when one logs into the server. You could add static text to this files which will be displayed on login. If you require dynamic content I recommend using /etc/profile file to set this welcome, since this file will be executed once any user logging into the system. You could just type in `echo ${USER}` to print the details on to the terminal.